# SpriteKit animations lost in iOS 10.2 when copying SKNode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This problem I am having only appears in iOS 10.2. I have created an sks file containing objects that will be spawned in the game. This scene also contains animations for each object. In the View Controller, this scene is loaded and the obstacles are added to an array.

```
var obstacles = [SKNode]()
for child in SKScene(fileNamed: "Hazards.sks")!.children {
    obstacles.append(child)
}
```

These obstacles are copyied into the GameScene when they are needed

```
 addChild(obstacles[number].copy() as! SKNode)
```

A new animation is run on the node moveing it from the top of the screen to the bottom. This animation has no problem. All this code runs fine in iOS 10.1. The line copying the node to the scene happens to crashed in iOS 9.3.

I have the problem to be the scene which the nodes were copied from were loosing their animation because they were being copied from a scene that had already been deinitialized. Creating a strong reference to the scene fixed the problem for some of the nodes. Copying the node to an array instead of adding a reference to it fixed the problem completely.
The new code in the View Controller looks like this:

```
var obstacles = [SKNode]()
for child in SKScene(fileNamed: "Hazards.sks")!.children {
    obstacles.append(child.copy() as! SKNode)
}
```

I still am wonder why this is only a problem with iOS 10.2.